# TypeError: (0 , _redux_slices_loginAuthApiSlice__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useLoginMutation) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, rtk-query

NextJS 14
How to resolve the above issue?, Please guide me if anything wrong
Below are the package version
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
"next": "^14.0.4",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",
"react-redux": "^9.0.4",
"redux": "^5.0.0",

[image]

I have added data type any but no luck

Answer (score -1):

Try to use It!!
Upvote if that correct answer to ur question

```html
export const {
  useLoginMutation();
} = loginAuthApiSlice

/*
* import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice{try to write type of 
* the file}";
* or attempt to use { apiSlice } without gaps | apiSlice | 
*/
```